# Windows boot loop after installing Windows and the linux on a new partition

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I have a Windows OS on my main partition in my laptop. I shrinked it and created a new partition on which I tried to install Windows (originally wanted 2 partitions of Windows until I finish installing everything I need on the new Windows partition). 
It turns out that the installation was corrupt and after copying the files and booting the Windows installer could not finish the installation so I decided to replace it with an installation of Kubuntu. 
I installed Kubuntu on the same partition successfully and now when I start the computer I can choose Kubuntu or Windows but if I choose Windows I run into an endless boot loop. 
When booting - for a split second I can see the blue screen that resembles the  windows multiboot for choosing between the old and new Windows installation (which I think is supposed to be available only when booting during the Windows installation).

I just want to fix the boot configuration and get the old Windows copy to work again. Any ideas as to how to do that? It my understanding that I need to do that with the windows boot manager since it's trying to boot into the new windows installation partition (which is now taken by the Kubuntu one).

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: Try to fix MBR | press shift + f10 while you are on the start screen of installing new windows | enter the following command in the command prompt that opened | `bootrec /FixMbr`
`bootrec /FixBoot`
`bootrec /RebuildBcd`

Comment: Tried that several times with no success. It looks like the split second when Windows is trying to load it's not reacting to keystrokes or I'm not fast enough :)
Any ideas as to how to be able to fix this by booting from a USB stick and then updating the MBR ?